# How to extend multiple classes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make class `User` extend both Authenticatable and Model at the same time:

```
class User extends Authenticatable

class User extends Model
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Multiple inheritance doesn't exist in PHP.

Comment: Extend `Authenticatable` from `Model` and `User` from `Authenticatable` if it's ok !

Comment: the class ```User``` already extends from ```Model```
https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The User class by default extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticable`. This class already extends the Model class.

[Check the API for more information](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.html)